# Difference between red5 and wowza

Tags: red5, wowza

I am trying to set up a streaming media server. I tried wowza and found it very well documented. Its forums are very active.

I also checked red5. Red5 originated in 2005 whereas wowza started in 2007. Red5 is open source too. The past links to red5 documentation are almost dead. Is wowza a proprietary version of red5? Or red5 evolved into wowza just like rtmpd into evostream?

How do i set up red5 to capture an rtsp stream of the following format and publish it to rtmp?

```
 rtsp://username:password@<Camera IP Address>:554/axis-media/media.amp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer half.  Red5 and Wowza are completely seperate projects.  Wowza is closed source while red5 is open source.  Wowza did not evolve out of red5.  I don't know a feature by feature comparison between the two projects.

Scott, Wowza

Answer (score 2):

Wowza is quite mature than Red5. Red 5 is an open source effort that still has many bugs (I tried up to version 0.9). Documentation is critical about Red5, there is no support (only some mailing lists). Wowza has a complete [forum](https://www.wowza.com/community/) with different topics and solid [documentation](https://www.wowza.com/docs/). Actually I have a Wowza platform with excellent mobile support, which could never be achieved with Red5 (audio problems).

Answer (score 0):

On the Red5Server website there is a [feature comparison](https://www.red5server.com/red5-vs-wowza/) of the two products.